# Powershell remote: How to troubleshoot error code 14

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a `powershell` script which will run a long test remotely. The test will be running there for few hours. See code like below.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteIP -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock { 
        param ($runTestFolder,$runtestPath,$testsuiteOption)
        if ($(Test-Path -Path $runtestPath) -eq $false) {
            Write-Error "Run_Test.exe is not found from the path specified. "
            return "ERROR_RUN_TEST.EXE_DO_NOT_EXIST"
        }
        
        cmd /c "cd $runTestFolder && $runtestPath /s $testsuiteOption"

        return "COMPLETED."
    } -ArgumentList $runTestFolder,$runTestPath,$TestSuiteOption
```

But after about two hours, it throw this error. How do I debug it? I checked "about_Remote_Troubleshooting" but it does not mention the error code at all.

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: Error with error code 14 occurred while calling method WSManPluginReceiveResult. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`New-SessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssessionoption?view=powershell-7.2) MS Docs:

> The **IdleTimeoutMs** value of the default **Microsoft.PowerShell** session configuration is 7200000 milliseconds (2 hours). Its **MaxIdleTimeoutMs** value is 2147483647 milliseconds (>24 days). The default value of the WSMan shell idle time-out (`WSMan:\<ComputerName>\Shell\IdleTimeout`) is 7200000 milliseconds (2 hours).

---

The alternatives are:

- Establish a [`New-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession?view=powershell-7.2) setting the *IdleTimeout* to it's max value and connect to it using the [`-Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-4--use-a-session-to-run-a-series-of-commands-that-share-data) paramater:

```
$pso = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 2147483647
$pss = New-PSSession $remoteIP -Credential $credential -SessionOption $pso

Invoke-Command -Session $pss -ScriptBlock {
    # script do something
}

Remove-PSSession $pss
```

- Use the [`-SessionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-15--use-a-session-option) parameter on `Invoke-Command`:

```
$pso = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 2147483647

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteIP -ScriptBlock {
    # script do something
} -Credential $credential -SessionOption $pso
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!